# Why is FindInstance failing when I relax a set of constraints?

Tags: equation-solving, algorithm, geometry

I'm attempting to use FindInstance to generate coordinate sets for plausible triangles with edge length distance constraints.  E.g.:

```
PlaneDimensionXYnm = 1000;
TriangleEdgeDistance = 400;

TriangleSolution = {};
While[Length[TriangleSolution] == 0,
  x1 = RandomReal[{200, PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200}];
  y1 = RandomReal[{200, PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200}];

TriangleSolution = FindInstance[  
    EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}] == TriangleEdgeDistance &&  
    EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x3, y3}] == TriangleEdgeDistance &&  
    EuclideanDistance[{x2, y2}, {x3, y3}] == TriangleEdgeDistance &&  
    x2 >= 200 && y2 >= 200 &&  
    x3 >= 200 &&  y3 >= 200 &&  
    x2 <= PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200 &&  
    y2 <= PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200 &&  
    x3 <= PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200 &&  
    y3 <= PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200, {x2, y2, x3, y3}];
    ];

TriangleCoordinates = N[{x2, y2, x3, y3} /. TriangleSolution[[1]]];
```

While the above script works fine (albeit inefficiently, but it doesn't matter for me), the below script fails:

```
TriangleSolution = {};
TriangleEdgeDistance = 400;

While[Length[TriangleSolution] == 0,
  x1 = RandomReal[{200, PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200}];
  y1 = RandomReal[{200, PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200}];  

TriangleSolution = FindInstance[  
    EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}] > TriangleEdgeDistance &&  
    EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x3, y3}] > TriangleEdgeDistance &&  
    EuclideanDistance[{x2, y2}, {x3, y3}] > TriangleEdgeDistance &&  
    x2 >= 200 && y2 >= 200 &&  
    x3 >= 200 && y3 >= 200 &&  
    x2 <= PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200 &&  
    y2 <= PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200 &&  
    x3 <= PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200 &&  
    y3 <= PlaneDimensionXYnm - 200, {x2, y2, x3, y3}];
    ];

TriangleCoordinates = N[{x2, y2, x3, y3} /. TriangleSolution[[1]]];
```

All I've done here is relax the constraint that the triangle edges should be the same length, and required that the edges all be greater than a certain length.  Why does FindInstance now fail?

Comment: I can't seem to find it, but did you impose the triangle inequality anywhere?

Comment: @J.M. In the second instance, I simply require that all of the edges are larger than "TriangleEdgeDistance".

Comment: First one does not give a result either, for the fairly obvious reason that `TriangleEdgeDistance` is not defined. This violates UR1 ("unwritten rule #1), which states "make sure code claimed to work actually does work".

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Ok, good point.  I defined a value for TriangleEdgeDistance.

Comment: Both now work for me. The second one takes considerable time, but eventually breaks down and confesses it has found a result. This is in version 9, on a 64-bit Windows machine (noted in case there is some platform-dependent weirdness going on).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Why do you suspect the less constrained problem takes considerably more time?  I'm asking this question here more for the sake of understanding than anything else.

Comment: That I simply do not know. Will make inquiries.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For nonlinear systems of equations and inequalities `FindInstance` uses the cylindrical algebraic decomposition (CAD) algorithm. The algorithm may use equational constraints to simplify the computations by "eliminating" variables. Hence replacing equations with inequalities can make the problem harder.

Another problem in this example is that `EuclideanDistance` returns a quadratic radical. The CAD algorithm deals only with polynomial systems. `FindInstance` polynomializes the input by replacing radicals with new variables and adding the corresponding quadratic equations. The CAD algorithm is very sensitive to adding new variables - its worst-case complexity in the number of variables is doubly-exponential. Since `EuclideanDistance` is a square root of an expression that is always nonnegative, in this example the quadratic radicals may be removed without adding new variables, namely by squaring both sides of each equation or inequality. If you use

```
EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}]^2 == TriangleEdgeDistance^2

EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}]^2 > TriangleEdgeDistance^2
```

in you code the example runs twice faster in the equation case and ~100 times faster in the inequality case.