# Can I force a function to quit and return some value after a certain amount of time has passed during its evaluation?

Tags: functions, evaluation, algorithm

Imagine I provide some random input to function like `FindInstance[]`, and I observe that, despite the existence of good solutions, the function will, with some probability, indefinitely evaluate without success.  For an example, please see my earlier question: [Why is FindInstance failing when I relax a set of constraints?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23720/why-is-findinstance-failing-when-i-relax-a-set-of-constraints)

Can I somehow force the function to return, say, an empty list {} after some time $T$ has passed?

Comment: Did you check `TimeConstraint`?

Comment: @Spawn1701D That seems not to work for FindInstance?

Comment: @Spawn1701D I'm looking for something I can also wrap around some section of code to force it to restart or quit after some time has passed.

Comment: There is also the wrapper/Function variant `TimeConstrained`.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Yup, that seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TimeConstrained[expr, t, failexpr]` returns *failexpr* if the time constraint *t* is not met.